# Why does " ^C " appear on putty and makes me write the mysql code again?

Tags: mysql, putty

[image: Click here for the screenshot]

As you see, the first time I wrote the code, the ^C appeared. Then I had to write exactly the same again and then everything worked completely fine. What is wrong?

Comment: `^C` appears when you type Control-C to interrupt a query.

Comment: Just spontaneously appeared out of nowhere? How long after you wrote the code? This is slightly vague.

Comment: @Barmar It appears frequently and I have not been using CTRL+C

Comment: @underscore_d It appears when I press Enter after done writing

Comment: This same thing happens to me! I am yet to figure out the cause for this. It does not happen to any of my colleagues. It happens quite frequently on my machine. When typing linux commands, sql queries etc, it will randomly "Press or insert " ^C. I am not pressing it, it just happens itself!

Comment: If this is happening it's an OS or terminal emulator problem, not a programming question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about using terminal applications is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

`^C`is the command to end a process running in the CMD

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ctrl-c-and-ctrl-break-signals

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you will use Ctrl + c while using terminal or command prompt, control return will occur.